# Embed state outline map within US map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As a followup to my [question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528956/how-to-draw-outline-of-state-in-map) I would like to embed a state map outline (Indiana) in my map and I have tried several ways and googled many different methods. The closest I found to embedding an outline on google I have asked a question on SO already and gotten a JSFiddle response thanks to geocodezip but I cannot add it to my US map. I have the Java script code here in the link for the state map outline but I the code I have attached for whatever reason I cannot add the outline code despite fiddling with it extensively.

SO won't let me upload the image of my flightpath image. I have been stuck on this for weeks and would like to embed the state outline map as evidenced in this fiddle.

```
function myMap() {
  var dfw = new google.maps.LatLng(32.899809, -97.040335);

  var yul = new google.maps.LatLng(45.469738, -73.744919);

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: dfw,
    zoom: 4
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: dfw,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "DFW International Airport!"
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: yul,
    icon: "pinkball.png",
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    title: 'Click to zoom'
  });
  marker2.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Montréal–Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport!"
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker2);
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

  marker2.addListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
  });

  marker2.setMap(map);

  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [dfw, yul],
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jnzv4zj7) is the JSFiddle of the outline I would like to embed in the page.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle of the outline I would like to embed in the page. http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jnzv4zj7/

Comment: unless you work for w3schools you should not be asking us to debug code from their website.

Comment: in other words, post YOUR code

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include your comment (and probably a [mcve] that shows the problem, and indicate the errors you are getting, if any)

Comment: i could easily have have used JSfiddle or codepen...i attached the W3schools link so you could see what the flightpath looks like...read what i wrote..i said MY map....

Comment: I wrestled a bear... " would like to embed a state map outline (Indiana) in my map and I have tried several ways and googled many different methods. ".....please READ carefully what i wrote before you comment...like i said i posted MY code in another site to run it...

Comment: Thanks Mast and Sunny for your edits

Comment: here is a fixed version of what I was trying to do ....you guys can see what was done here its my code http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBQUTOYXHX9N